# React state comparison with objects and nested arrays

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-state-management

I am trying to compare state against a previous version of the same object (**useRef**) to detect for changes.

The object that loads into state with **useEffect** looks like this:

```
{
  active: true,
  design: [
    {
      existing: '55Xgm53McFg1Bzr3qZha',
      id: '38fca',
      options: ['John Smith', 'Jane Doe'],
      required: true,
      title: 'Select your name',
      type: 'Selection List'
    },
   {
      existing: '55Xgm53McFg1Bzr3qZha',
      id: '38fca',
      options: ['John Smith', 'Jane Doe'],
      required: true,
      title: 'Select your name',
      type: 'Selection List'
    },
  ],
  icon: '',
  id: '92yIIZxdFYoWk3FMM0vI',
  projects: false,
  status: true,
  title: 'Prestarts'
}
```

This is how I load in my app object and define a comparitor state (**previousApp**) to compare it and detect changes (with lodash) this all works great until I change a value in the **design** array.

```
const [app, setApp] = useState(null)
const [edited, setEdited] = useState(false)
const previousApp = useRef(null)

 useEffect(() => {
    if (app === null) {
      getApp(someAppId).then(setApp).catch(window.alert)
    }
    if (previousApp.current === null && app) {
      previousApp.current = { ...app }
    }
    if (previousApp.current && app) {
      _.isEqual(app, previousApp.current) ? setEdited(false) : setEdited(true)
    }
  }, [app])
```

For example I change the input value of app.design[0].title = 'testing' with the following code:

```
const updateItem = e => {
  let newApp = { ...app }
  let { name, value } = e.target
  newApp.design[0][name] = value
  setApp(newApp)
}
```

This works in the sense that it updates my app state object but not that it detects any changes in comparison to **previousApp.current**

When I console log **app** and **previousApp** after changing both values, they are identical. Its seems to update my **previousApp** value aswell for some reason.

---

Rearranging the **design** array works as expected and detects a change with the following function:

```
const updateDesign = e => {
  let newApp = { ...app }
  newApp.design = e
  setApp(newApp)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It probably wasn't detecting any difference because the **array** present in the `design` property was keeping the same reference.

When you do this:

```
let newApp = { ...app }
```

You're creating a new object for your app, but the property values of that object will remain the same, because it's a shallow copy. Thus, the `design` **array** (which is an object, and therefore is handled by reference) will keep its value (the reference) unaltered.

I think this would also solve your problem:

```
const updateItem = e => {
  let newApp = { ...app };
  let newDesign = Array.from(app.design);  // THIS CREATES A NEW ARRAY REFERENCE FOR THE 'design' PROPERTY
  let { name, value } = e.target;
  newDesign[0][name] = value;
  setApp({
    ...newApp,
    design: newDesign
  });
}
```

Comment: I had no idea the array was still used with reference. I had just assumed {...app} would make a duplicate of the entire object and its children. The more you know, thank you for your explanation.

Answer (score 0):

I found that using lodash's cloneDeep function i was able to remove the strange link that was occuring between previousApp and App; Even though I used {...app}

See the following:

```
if (previousApp.current === null && app) {
   previousApp.current = cloneDeep(app)
}
```